# address book exercise I'd want it to split each line of the list but it takes just the last one

Tags: python, class, oop, for-loop

As exercise I have to implement an Address Book which must be able to read the content of a file containing the contacts and perform CRUD (Cre-ate,Read,Update,Delete). I'm having some troubles with the address book, in particular with the definition of the **init** method. I thought that in this method I should put the attributes (in this case there aren't) and the basic function the class must do in order to perform the required functions(CRUD). The contacts are in a txt file, so the class must read the file and copy everything in a list so that it'll be able to modify it. So I thought about this code, but if I print the contacts list, it returns just the last line.It seems like the for cycle doesn't work. I can't find the error.

```
class Contact:  
    def __init__(self,name,surname,mail):
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.mail=mail

    def __repr__(self):
        return"{},{},{}".format(self.name,self.surname,self.mail)

class AddressBook:    
    def __init__(self):
        File= open("contacts.txt").read()
        self.contacts=[]
        lines=File.splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            contact_section=line.split(',') 
        self.contacts.append(Contact(contact_section[0],contact_section[1],contact_section[2]))
```

Comment: `self.contacts.append(...)` should be inside the loop

Comment: some extra tips `contact_section[0],contact_section[1],contact_section[2]` can be replaced with `*contact_section` (assuming each section has 3 entries). and your file opening/loop could be a little better: `with open("contacts.txt") as fh: for line in fh:` (fix the indentation of course) this makes you parse the file as you read it instead of first reading the whole file and then working on it

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips! I didn't notice the indentation error

Answer (score 1):

The issue with AddressBook is that you are iterating over the lines
but you only add the last one to the list.

```
def __init__(self):
    File= open("contacts.txt").read()
    self.contacts=[]
    lines=File.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        contact_section=line.split(',') 
    # CHECK THE INDENTATION IS NOT INSIDE THE FOR LOOP
    self.contacts.append(Contact(contact_section[0],contact_section[1],contact_section[2]))
```

just put the this line

```
self.contacts.append(Contact(contact_section[0],contact_section[1],contact_section[2]))
```

inside the for loop like this

```
def __init__(self):
    File= open("contacts.txt").read()
    self.contacts=[]
    lines=File.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        contact_section=line.split(',')
        self.contacts.append(
            Contact(contact_section[0],contact_section[1],contact_section[2])
        )
```